# Mount all mountable partitions of a removable disk with diskutil

Tags: disk-utility, mount

I have a USB drive containing 2 FAT partitions which are automatically mounted when the drive is plugged in. If I run `diskutil unmounDisk <device>` and then `diskutil mountDisk <device>` I'd expect to be back on the initial state.

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 DCD23031-6322-4269-A142-CD36C8FD95D7
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *7.8 GB     disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 flash-boot              1.7 GB     disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         197.1 MB   disk2s2
   3:                      Linux                         197.1 MB   disk2s3
   4:             Windows_FAT_32 flash-conf              21.0 MB    disk2s5
   5:                      Linux                         4.2 MB     disk2s6
```

See `/dev/disk2`. The two FAT partitions are currently mounted:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s5 on /Volumes/flash-conf (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/flash-boot (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

Now lets unmount:

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
```

The partitions were indeed unmounted:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, no browse)
```

Now lets try mounting back:

```
$ diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2
Volume(s) mounted successfully
```

The operation succeeds, according to `diskutil`, but the partitions are still not mounted:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, what's the correct way of mounting a disk back again?

---

I'm on OS X 10.11.3.

---

EDIT 1: `fdisk` output:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk2
Password:
Disk: /dev/disk2        geometry: 951/255/63 [15280192 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
*1: 0C   64   0   1 - 1023   3  32 [      8192 -    3276800] Win95 FAT32L
 2: 83 1023   3  32 - 1023   3  32 [   3284992 -     385024] Linux files*
 3: 83 1023   3  32 - 1023   3  32 [   3670016 -     385024] Linux files*
 4: 0F 1023   3  32 - 1023   3  32 [   4055040 -      65536] Extended LBA
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0C 1023   3  32 - 1023   3  32 [   4063232 -      40960] Win95 FAT32L
 2: 05 1023   3  32 - 1023   3  32 [   4112256 -       8320] Extended DOS
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 83 1023   3  32 - 1023   3  32 [   4112384 -       8192] Linux files*
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: My first thought was to try to recreate your external drive. Immediately, I realized this can not be done, since your MBR partitioned external disk has 6 partitions. Since the MBR partitioning scheme table can only contain 4 entries, some these partitions must be defined in extended boot records (EBRs). To view the EBRs, you would need to update your question with the output from the command `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk2`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I've edited the question with the output.

Comment: @klanomath The image is a Resin.io (https://resin.io) Intel NUC image. You can register, create a NUC application and download the image from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I can't verify this, I think the problem is related to the *nodev* flag of the partitions. In theory the *nodev* flag doesn't allow a non-root user to create a device node like /dev/disk2s5. So you have to prepend `sudo` to remount the mountable partitions of the disk.

The following should work:

- Create mount points: `mkdir mnt1` and `mkdir mnt2`
- Mount the partitions

  ```
  sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk2s1 ~/mnt1 
  #and respectively for the 2nd partition
  sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk2s5 ~/mnt2
  ```

---

Rechecked with a real thumb drive:

Simply use:

```
sudo diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2
```

instead of `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2`

Comment: Manually mounting the partitions work, however this is being used in an application where I'm interested in auto-mounting whatever is mountable (according to OS X) automatically. I might be able to scan the drive for FAT partitions and trigger a mount on those, but I have to specify the mount directory (the suggestions from the end doesn't work), and it doesn't cover other partition types that I might have to handle.

Comment: @jviotti Updated answer

Comment: Adding `sudo` also works on my machine. @jviotti: Do you have to use a MBR partitioning scheme? A scheme using a GUID Partition Table (GPT) would probably eliminate this problem.

Comment: Sadly I don't have control over the scheme. Turns out `sudo diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2` works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the `diskutil` command does not like partitions with the id of `0C` and, therefore, will not mount them.

Here is the test I preformed.

1. Using Yosemite OS X 10.10.5, I partitioned a 4 GB flash drive using
   a MBR scheme to have 5 equal sized FAT formatted partitions. This
   function is no longer permitted under El Capitan.
2. Removed flash drive, inserted flash drive, unmounted disk using
   `diskutil`, and mounted disk using `diskutil`. Everything works fine.
   No problems.
3. Boot to El Capitan OS X 10.11.4.
4. Removed flash drive, inserted flash drive, unmounted disk using
   `diskutil`, and mounted disk using `diskutil`. Everything works
   fine. No problems.

One difference I did note. Your `fdisk` output shows the id for the FAT formatted partitions as `0C`. Yosemite created these partitions, on my Mac, using the id of `0B`. I used the `fdisk` command to change the id of the ***first*** partition to `0C`. Now when I unmount and mount the flash drive using the `diskutil` command, the first partition does not mount. The remaining 4 do.

Ironically, if I use the command

```
diskutil mount /dev/disk1s1
```

the first partition, on the flash drive, mounts. (On my computer, I am not using core storage, therefore, the flash drive is `disk1`.)

Comment: Great discovery. According to https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html, `0C` represents "WIN95 OSR2 FAT32, LBA-mapped" and `0B` represents `WIN95 OSR2 FAT32`. Doing `diskutil mount` on the specific partitions works. I'm looking forward to integrate this into an application to auto-mount whatever is mountable. A good enough solution, albeit hacky, would be to iterate through available partitions and call `diskutil mount <partition>` ignoring the exit code.

Comment: My experience with Windows is that it will often ignore the partition id. Instead, Windows will look directly into a partition and try to identify the file system. If windows recognizes a FAT or NTFS volume, it will mount the partition. I realize you are using OS X here, but I thought I would mention this anyway.